# Как работает if для булевого значения

Tags: java, if

```
boolean example[] = { true, false, false, true, true };

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (example[i]) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

Почему выводит результат `true,false,false,true,true`? По какой логике?
Я так понимаю, `if (example[i])` означает, что если данный элемент равен любому значению, то вывести `true`. Тогда почему результат не `true,true,true,true,true`?

Comment: `if(alca[i])` не означает если любое значение, а означает если значение true, соответственно вывод повторяет массив alca.

Comment: Значит везде где if(example[i]) по дефолту присваивается true?
т.е. это сокращение if(example[i] = true)?

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на мой вопрос

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Массив `example` содержит булевы переменные.

Оператор `if` вычисляет результат в скобках на истина\ложь и в зависимости от того, получится в итоге вычислений `true`  или `false`, выполняет одну из веток: сразу после скобок или после оператора `else`

Так как в вашем массиве уже булевы переменные, то вычисления на истина\ложь для них не требуется: аргумент условия уже содержит булево значение, которое оператор `if` может обработать напрямую.

В итоге, если развернуть ваш код, получится такое:

```
if (true) .. выполнить часть после скобок
if(false) ..  выполнить часть после else
if(false) ..   выполнить часть после else
if(true) ..  выполнить часть после скобок
if(true) ..  выполнить часть после скобок
```

Сама конструкция if - else читается следующим образом:

```
Если (что-то истинно) {выполнить это} иначе {выполнить это}
```

Comment: Так это то я и не понимаю, почему уже во втором случае когда if(false) он проскакивает через первый вывод System.out.println("true") и переходит в else c выводом System.out.println("false"), т.е. изначально уже есть какой-то шаблон по которому первый statement выполняется для значений true и второй statement для false?

Comment: @revcik Читайте внимательнее - если в скобках получилось true - выполняется первый блок, если false - второй блок (после else), не знаю о каком шаблоне идет речь, но  так работает  оператор `if` по замыслу создателей языка Java

Comment: Я так и понял, спасибо.

Comment: @pavlofff а есть какой-то сакраментальный смысл в том, что у вас в первом случае есть пробел между `if` и `(`, а в других - нет?

Comment: @Regent Не думаю.. похоже на то, что мне хотелось скорее напечатать все это